# An Army of Ones

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion, bitwise

I've been practicing using recursion lately and thought this was a case where it would prove really useful, is this good use or is there some superior non-recursive way to go about it?

**Challenge**:

> Write a program which determines the number of 1 bits in the internal representation of a given integer.

**Specifications**:

> The first argument is a path to a file.
>   The file contains integers, one per line.

**Solution**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryOnes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            printBinaryOnesCount(input.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private static void printBinaryOnesCount(String line) {
        System.out.println(binaryOnesCount(Integer.parseInt(line)));
    }

    private static int binaryOnesCount(int n) {
        if (n < 2) { return n; }
        return binaryOnesCount(n / 2) + n % 2;
    }
}
```

**Sample Input**:

> 10
>   22
>   56

**Sample Output**:

> 2
>   3
>   3

Comment: See [`Integer.bitCount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-)

Comment: There are a lot of good methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: `binaryOnesCount(-5)` will return `-5`. Is that what you wwant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code's general structure is decent. The Single-Responsibility-Principle is established by having relatively clear logic structures in the `main`, `print*` and `binaryOnesCount` methods. While the basic structure is fine, the actual bitcount algorithm is very inefficient.

Recursion is not the answer to this problem.

Even if recurstion was the solution, I don't like how you find the low bit, and I don't like your terminal conditions. Additionally, actual bitwise operations should be used to count actual bits.

Additionally, your continued use of 1-liners for conditional blocks is disheartening.

So, if you *have* to use recursion, something like:

```
private static int binaryOnesCount(int n) {
    // clear terminal block.
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int lowbit = n & 1; // is the low bit set.

    // Use an unsigned right-shift to strip the low bit.
    return lowbit + binaryOnesCount( n >>> 1);

}
```

But, Recursion is not the answer. It has an expensive overhead in the stack.

A simpler solution is:

```
private static int binaryOnesCount(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Of course, this is all reinventing the wheel.... There's a really cool bitwise implementaton using fancy masks and shifts, that can do it really fast. It's already implemented in: [`Integer.bitCount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-)

See [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.bitCount%28int%29) (HD is [Hacker's Delight book](http://www.amazon.ca/Hackers-Delight-Edition-Henry-Warren/dp/0321842685)):

```
public static int bitCount(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-2
    i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
    i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    i = i + (i >>> 8);
    i = i + (i >>> 16);
    return i & 0x3f;
}
```

Comment: Not at all familiar with the bit-wise stuff. Didn't realize there already was a built in method. Haha, and I felt so good when I came up with this solution. Thanks for the enlightenment. What's wrong with using 1 liners?

Comment: @Legato 1 liners are hard to read most of the time, since it's compacting everything.

Comment: Even in this case? I tend to use it if it's short and only a single effect, should I just altogether forego using them?

Comment: By Java code convention you should not use one liners. See 7.4 in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449

Comment: Regarding the library method: more importantly, it can be JITed to `POPCNT`, a single x86 instruction.

Comment: @barq that was a good read but it didn't say anything about one liners.